# Display logo in ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have an action bar but have only been to display the title of application or/and the title of the current fragment activity into it. I would want to display logo in it, and any attempts to add a logo have been unsuccessful.

Below is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends  ActionBarActivity {

    private String[] mOptionMenu;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private RelativeLayout mDrawerRelativeLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mTitleSection;
    private CharSequence mTitleApp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView button=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logobutton);


        mOptionMenu = new String[] { "Opción 1", "Opción 2", "Opción 3" };
         mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         mDrawerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)
         findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
         mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_drawer);
         mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         mOptionMenu));

         mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {

         Fragment fragment = null;

         switch (position) {
         case 0:
         fragment = new FirstFragment();
         break;
         case 1:
         fragment = new SecondFragment();
         break;
         case 2:
         fragment = new ThirdFragment();
         break;
         }

         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

         fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

         mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

         mTitleSection = mOptionMenu[position];
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);

         mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);
         }
         });
         mDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true);
         mTitleSection = getTitle();
         mTitleApp = getTitle();

         mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
         R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
         R.string.drawer_close) {

         public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
             getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);
             getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo);

         ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.this);
         }

         public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
             getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);
         ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.this);
         getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo);

         }
         };

         mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ;
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

I tried adding this line in the code, but no image is being displayed:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
```

I also have a similar concern, in that I want the logo to be clickable and to direct user to the MainActivity

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable Logo feature on you ActionBar by calling `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)`.

Comment: I have added        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true); under onCreate

Comment: but for some reason it is still not displayin

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `OnCreate` in this order:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, you can set `android:logo="@drawable/logo"` on your `<application>` node, and/or `android:icon="@drawable/icon"` for each `<activity>` node.

Comment: apply these two options, but unfortunately it is still not displaying

Answer (score 0):

In your mainfest file, add under `<application>`:

```
android:icon="@drawable/logo"
```

Comment: thanks. This has already been added. I feel the issue is more related to the code